# Sticky header hides behind 2nd header

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I'm a first time WP user and building my site. I'm trying to create a sticky header, but the header-2nd-row covers the header-1st-row.

```
/*sticky header*/

 .headroom--not-top {
-moz-transform: translateY(0) !important;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0) !important;
-o-transform: translateY(0) !important;
-ms-transform: translateY(0) !important;
transform: translateY(0) !important;
}

.header-layout2 .headroom--not-top .header-2nd-row {
display: block;
}
```

This is the link to view the site:
https://jaggedlinesmagazine.com/?page_id=51&preview=1&_ppp=0d481f5893

Is there anything I can do to fix this?
Thank you!